# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Xcode from my c++ wrapper in objective-c++ and swift bridging header

Tags: c++, swift, objective-c++

I'm working on a app using openCV and a utility class "Detector" created in C++. I want to create a objective-c++ wrapper "DetectorWrapper" for the c++ class and use this wrapper in Swift (bridging header). But know when I try to call a fonction from DetectorWrapper, my app crash with the error : EXC_BAD_ACCESS

I read sowewhere that to be allow to use the objective-c++ class in Swift, I cannot include c++ file in the DetectorWrapper.h so I use the type id.

Here is my c++ class: "Detector.h"

```cpp
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
class Detector
{
public:

    // Constructor
    Detector(int inputPlayerIdx);

    // Scan the input video frame
    void scanFrame(cv::Mat frame);

    // Tracking API
    bool isTracking();
};
```

My wrapper: "DetectorWrapper.h"

```c
@interface DetectorWrapper : NSObject
@end

@interface DetectorWrapper ()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) id bld;

- (id)init: (int) inputPlayerIdx;
- (void)dealloc;
- (void) scanFrame: (UIImage*) frame;
- (bool) isTracking;
@end
```

"DetectorWrapper.mm"

```c
#import "DetectorWrapper.h"
#import "Detector.hpp"
#import "UIImage+OpenCV.h"
@implementation DetectorWrapper
@synthesize bld = _bld;

- (id)init: (int) inputPlayerIdx {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _bld = (__bridge id) new Detector(inputPlayerIdx);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    //[self->_bld dealloc];
    //[super dealloc];
    //delete _bld;
}
- (void) scanFrame: (UIImage*) frame{
    [self->_bld scanFrame:frame];
}
- (bool) isTracking{
    return [self->_bld isTracking];
}
@end
```

Using this in Swift:

```swift
let detector = DetectorWrapper(2)
detector.isTracking()
```

with the file "Detector.h" in Bridging Header.

I got the "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error when calling for .isTracking
I don't understand the problem at all and how to figure it out. 
Maybe I just made a mistake coding my objective-c++ wrapper, I'm not used to this language. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem here is that a C++ object is used as if it was an Objective-C object, and these kinds of objects are not interchangeable.

For illustration purposes and for simplicity, let's eliminate the `scanFrame` method.  Then `DetectorWrapper.h` becomes

```
@interface DetectorWrapper : NSObject
- (id)init: (int) inputPlayerIdx;
- (void)dealloc;
- (bool) isTracking;
@end
```

and the wrapper implementation:

```
@implementation DetectorWrapper
{
    // Instance variable to hold a C++ object pointer
    Detector * ptrDetector;
}

- (id)init: (int) inputPlayerIdx {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        ptrDetector = new Detector(inputPlayerIdx);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    // Don't want to leak the C++ Detector instance
    delete ptrDetector;
}

- (bool) isTracking{        
    return ptrDetector->isTracking();
}
@end
```

Please note that when you re-introduce `scanFrame`, you won't be able to just pass `UIImage*` to `ptrDetector->scanFrame()`, which takes `cv::Mat`, you'll have to do some magic in your wrapper's `scanFrame` to convert between the 2 types, but that's a topic in its own right, I think.  BTW, I'm assuming that in your example `Detector.h` and `Detector.hpp` refer to the same file, it's just a typo.